# how to inject ant build time to an html page

Tags: html, ant

Anyone know how to inject an ant build date time stamp into an html page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you refer ant, I assume you're on Java.
You can use tstamp task and echo to a property file. This property file can be bundled into the jar so that the application can read the property and display the value as required.

Ex:

```
<target name="build.timestamp">        
<tstamp>
<format property="build.timestamp" pattern="yyyy.MM.dd-hh.mm.ss" locale="en,UK"/>
</tstamp>
<echo message="tstamp=${build.timestamp}" file="build-timestamp.properties"/>
</target>
```

This will create a build-timestamp.properties in current ant directory.
Jar it up as a regular resource file along with application classes so that it becomes available at app run time.

Comment: When I refer to ant, I Am on Java. When you say make property available as a resource to my app, do you mean during build time or at run?